# MAX function and GROUP BY function not working together

Tags: sql, join

I want to list the name professor who teaches "java", number of times he taught and latest year and term he taught.

I tried this query but it's giving two rows with same name.

```
SELECT i.I_FNAME, COUNT(f.I_ID) as myCount, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
FROM 
  INSTRUCTOR i
JOIN TEACHINGQUALIFICATION t
  ON i.I_ID = t.I_ID
JOIN COURSE c
  ON c.C_ID = t.C_ID
JOIN COURSEOFFERING f
  ON i.I_ID = f.I_ID  
WHERE c.C_TITLE =  'java'
  GROUP BY t.I_ID, i.I_FNAME, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
  ORDER BY f.CO_YEAR desc
```

**output:**

```
1    Gaurav    1    4   2006
2    Gaurav    1    1   2000
```

**Expected output:**

```
1    Gaurav    2    4   2006
```

**code with error:**

I also tried this code with the condition  "AND f.CO_YEAR= MAX (f.CO_YEAR)" but it's showing this error " group function is not allowed here"

```
SELECT  t.I_ID, i.I_FNAME, COUNT(f.I_ID) as Cnt, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
FROM 
  INSTRUCTOR i
JOIN TEACHINGQUALIFICATION t
  ON i.I_ID = t.I_ID
JOIN COURSE c
  ON c.C_ID = t.C_ID
JOIN COURSEOFFERING f
  ON i.I_ID = f.I_ID  
WHERE c.C_TITLE =  'itec801' AND f.CO_YEAR= MAX (f.CO_YEAR)
  GROUP BY t.I_ID, i.I_FNAME, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
  ORDER BY f.CO_YEAR desc
```

---

**UPDATED**

---

This code is showing the output with latest year but the problem is when it fetches the latest row, counter stops there and it shows 1 value. But i want to count all the row and then only display latest year.

```
SELECT  t.I_ID, i.I_FNAME, COUNT(f.I_ID) as Cnt, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
    FROM 
      INSTRUCTOR i
    JOIN TEACHINGQUALIFICATION t
      ON i.I_ID = t.I_ID
    JOIN COURSE c
      ON c.C_ID = t.C_ID
    JOIN COURSEOFFERING f
      ON i.I_ID = f.I_ID  
 JOIN
    (
    SELECT I_ID, MAX(CO_YEAR) LatestYear
    FROM COURSEOFFERING GROUP BY I_ID
    ) 
  f2 ON f.I_ID = f2.I_ID AND f.CO_YEAR = f2.LatestYear

    WHERE c.C_TITLE =  'itec801' 
      GROUP BY t.I_ID, i.I_FNAME, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
     having  f.CO_YEAR= MAX (f.CO_YEAR)
      ORDER BY f.CO_YEAR desc
```

**New output:**

```
1    Gaurav    1    4   2006
```

**Expected output:**

```
1    Gaurav    2    4   2006
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this query, i haven't tried but:

```
SELECT  i.I_FNAME, COUNT(f.I_ID) as Cnt, MAX(f.CO_TERMNUMBER), MAX(f.CO_YEAR)
FROM 
  INSTRUCTOR i
JOIN TEACHINGQUALIFICATION t
  ON i.I_ID = t.I_ID
JOIN COURSE c
  ON c.C_ID = t.C_ID
JOIN COURSEOFFERING f
  ON i.I_ID = f.I_ID
WHERE c.C_TITLE =  'itec801'
  GROUP BY i.I_FNAME
```

Comment: It worked a bit for me but it's showing only one professor's name from the latest date. It has to show all distinct professors with count who taught same course 'itec801' with their respective latest date.

Comment: Please check your on conditions of join.

Answer (score 0):

```
   If you have aggeragate function then use having statement like and must below  order :
     select * from table
     where cond...
     group by ...
     having cond ...
     order by..
    =======================
    Exapmle:

      SELECT  t.I_ID, i.I_FNAME, COUNT(f.I_ID) as Cnt, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
        FROM 
       INSTRUCTOR i
       left outer JOIN TEACHINGQUALIFICATION t  ON i.I_ID = t.I_ID
       left outer JOIN COURSE c  ON c.C_ID = t.C_ID
       left outer JOIN COURSEOFFERING f  ON i.I_ID = f.I_ID  
       WHERE c.C_TITLE =  'itec801' 
       GROUP BY t.I_ID, i.I_FNAME, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
       having  f.CO_YEAR= MAX (f.CO_YEAR)
       ORDER BY f.CO_YEAR desc
```

Comment: @vikram.. thank you for your help. I have updated the question. Please check once, you may help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the [Having clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29)

try this (i've not tested it)

```
SELECT  t.I_ID, i.I_FNAME, COUNT(f.I_ID) as Cnt, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
FROM 
  INSTRUCTOR i
JOIN TEACHINGQUALIFICATION t
  ON i.I_ID = t.I_ID
JOIN COURSE c
  ON c.C_ID = t.C_ID
JOIN COURSEOFFERING f
  ON i.I_ID = f.I_ID  
WHERE c.C_TITLE =  'itec801'
  GROUP BY t.I_ID, i.I_FNAME, f.CO_TERMNUMBER, f.CO_YEAR
  HAVING f.CO_YEAR= MAX (f.CO_YEAR)
  ORDER BY f.CO_YEAR desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it's still showing the same output.

Comment: @kernel.. thank you for your help. I have updated the question. Please check once, you may help me out.